# Only one table's datas selected when join two tables in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, join

I used this code, but only one table's data selected.

I need to select all fields from two tables:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
                array('table' => 'tbl_users',
                    'alias' => 'Users',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'foreignKey' => 'assigned_by',
                    'fields' => 'Users.user',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'TravancoAdmin.assigned_by = Users.id'
                    )
                )
            );
            $options['conditions'] = array( 'TravancoAdmin.id' => $task_id);
$result = $this->find('all', $options);
        return $result ? $result : 1;
```

How can i get all fields from two tables?

If there is any mistakes in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the `'fields'` option out of `'joins'`. Otherwise $this->find will only fetch the fields for the current model. Remember to add all fields you need when you specify `'fields'`, both the ones for the current model and the ones you need from the table you're joining.

For example:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
                array('table' => 'tbl_users',
                    'alias' => 'Users',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'foreignKey' => 'assigned_by',
                    // 'fields' => 'Users.user', <- get rid of this
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'TravancoAdmin.assigned_by = Users.id'
                    )
                )
            );
$options['fields'] = array('TheModelThatThisRefersTo.*','Users.user'); // <- insert this
$options['conditions'] = array( 'TravancoAdmin.id' => $task_id);
$result = $this->find('all', $options);
return $result ? $result : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use reucrsive 2 and you have to relation the table into your moedl correctly if you want to retrieve your data.
After you the query you can have a big array with all fields, try to print with a var_dump to see if you have all your fields that you want

```
$this->recursive = 2;
$options['joins'] = array(
                array('table' => 'tbl_users',
                    'alias' => 'Users',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'foreignKey' => 'assigned_by',
                    'fields' => 'Users.user',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'TravancoAdmin.assigned_by = Users.id'
                    )
                )
            );
            $options['conditions'] = array( 'TravancoAdmin.id' => $task_id);
$result = $this->find('all', $options);
        return $result ? $result : 1;
```