# CakePHP nested associations, empty records errors

Tags: cakephp, associations, subquery

I have few tables which are connected (hasMany) like a tree: 1 -> 2 -> 3.
There are few records in table 1, table 2 and 3.

I'm using CakePHP to fetch all data from table 1 with connected table 2, which is connected with table 3. 
However few records in table 1 don't have any connected records in table 2. The same is in table 2, some records don't have connected records in table 3.

For the second situation scripts work fine. I get something like this:
1 -> 2 -> empty. But in the first situation, when data looks similar to: 1-> empty -> empty I get errors that table 3 doesn't exist.

Is there any solution to skip this errors and get pretty formatted association table as return to my query?

```
$options = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Table1.id' => $table1_ids
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Table2' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'id' => $table2_ids
                ),
                'Table3' => array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'date_end >' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                    ),
                    'fields' => array('id'),
                ),
                'fields' => array()
            ),
        ),
        'fields' => array('id', 'name')
    );
    $this->Table1->recursive = -1;
    $table1 = $this->Table1->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: hard to know without viewing the code that actually executes the script.

Comment: How are you getting those records? can you share the code?

Comment: I've added code. The solution for this could be for each record in Table2 I should retrieve for records in Table3. However it means a lot of queries to database...

Comment: What is strange, is that even for some records in Table 1, where Table1 -> empty -> empty, it's still working properly. I can't understand CakePHP. This is good framework for small applications but for more advanced ones it doesn't keep up.

Comment: I get database error that Table3 doesn't exist (?!). I don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really cakephp to blame here but your lack of understanding what `contain` does.

What you're looking for are [left joins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables), which is actually hinted in the documentation of `contain`.

Comment: When I'm using left joins I get only columns from one table. In DebugKit I can see that SQL query for joins retrieve columns from only one table. Why?

Comment: Okay! I've found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406081/only-one-tables-datas-selected-when-join-two-tables-in-cakephp)

Comment: Using joins causes that we don't get formatted data, I mean we have multiple the same records in Table 1:
`[1] -> [2]
[1] -> [2]` Is there any quick function in CakePHP to sort this data and assign all matching records from Table 2 to one associative table:
`[1] -> {
[2]
[2]
}`

Comment: Returned data is formatted, just not in the way you'd like. You can use members of cake's ``Hash`` utility class or iterate through them yourself and "fix" them to display in the way you want.

Comment: Can you give me some hint which function of Hash should I use?  I think none of them matches this problem... But I can be wrong

Comment: You can use Hash methods like extract and merge but if you're not comfortable with them or feel they are too much hassle, remember that you're now basically dealing with simple array management that php is best at. There are like 25 php functions that handle arrays but you can always foreach it.